# ¿Cómo hacer un Query de Suma y División con Variables de Sesión en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, php7

Tengo la siguiente tabla en mysql conectada a mi sistema en PHP.

```
 ID  |  PIN  |  respuesta1  |   respuesta2   |  respuesta3  |
  1    DD33         0                1               0
  2    DD33         1                3               1
  3    DD33         2                1               2
  4    EE42         2                1               2
```

Y en un inicio de sesión en PHP enlazo tanto usuario, contraseña y pin que corresponde al que tengo en la tabla de cuestionario con la finalidad de poder hacer en la interfaz de inicio de sesión las siguientes consultas:

Para conocer el total de cuestionarios resueltos:

```
 $cuenta = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT * FROM 
 cuestionario");
 $total = mysqli_num_rows($cuenta);
```

Para sumar el total de respuestas por columna:

```
 $query = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT SUM((respuesta1) + SUM(respuesta2) 
 + SUM(respuesta3) AS promedio FROM cuestionario"))/3;
 $promedio = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
```

Mi preguntas es como puedo trabajar mis consultas con el "pin" correspondiente al inicio de sesión si esta variable ya la tengo incluida y almacenada como:

```
  $pin = $_SESSION['pin'];
```

Me gustaría dividir toda la suma entre / $pin para que solo se divida en la cantidad de cuestionarios correspondientes al pin del inicio de sesión, pero no se cómo. Espero haber sido claro.
SALUDOS

Comment: Es decir buscas sustituir el 3 que colocas directo en la consulta por el valor de PIN?

Comment: Así es profesor @Aprendiz deseo sustituirlo para calcular el promedio, pero claramente únicamente para el pin correspondiente al inicio de sesión, tanto mis registros de usuarios y mi tabla cuestionario tienen el mismo campo llamado PIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente reorganiza tu consulta de este modo:

- Envuelve las 3 sumas dentro de una pareja de parentesis para reconocer todo eso como un grupo de operaciones a realizar primero y que el resultado de esta misma será dividida entre el valor que le llegue por `$pin`
- Fuera de esos parentesis que agrupan a las 3 sumas, realiza la división pasando la variable `$pin` con esta sintaxis: `'".$variableNombre."'`, es decir concatenándola a la sintaxis del SQL
- Asignale un alias a dicha consulta

Código

```
 $query = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT (SUM(respuesta1) + 
          SUM(respuesta2) + SUM(respuesta3)) / '".$pin."' AS promedio 
          FROM cuestionario");
 $promedio = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
```

Ahora para obtener el resultado ya sabemos que debemos hacer esto:

```
echo $promedio["promedio"];
```

Aclaración:

- Al tomar el `$pin` como variable esta funcionará tomando el valor que se generé y se le asigne por cada inicio de sesión lo cual la hace distinta y que sirva para lo que deseamos obtener

Comment: En este caso si inicio sesión y me toca el ''DD33' se supone que sólo hay 3 cuestionarios registrados con el 'DD33' por tanto mi suma se dividra entre 3.

Comment: El valor obtenido de la suma se dividirá entre el número que encuentre de `pin` , salvo que tu determines la cantidad de registros iguales por grupo de pines, ese valor será cambiante

Comment: Créo que editaré mi pregunta ya que pude avanzar un poco pero será más fácil encontrando la consulta correcta.